# Docusign Sender View: prepare page not displaying

Tags: docusignapi

I'm currently trying to display the first step of the sending process via the API, without much luck.

**The (filtered) URL I'm sending:**

```
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/sender
```

**DocuSign's (filtered) Response:**

```
{
  "url": "https://demo.docusign.net/Member/StartInSession.aspx?StartConsole=1&t={stuffhere}&DocuEnvelope={envelopeID}&send=1"
}
```

As per the [API docs](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Post%20Sender%20View.htm), I am changing `send=1` to `send=0` in order to start the sender on the prepare page, but I am still taken to the tagging page.

Has anyone had any success with `send=0` (when docs, senders and tabs have already been added)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested this in production and see the described behavior in the documentation

Does your user have **Use Advanced Sending** enabled?

It's at the very bottom of the sending first step page.

[image]

Comment: Yep! That was checked! Unchecking it did the trick! Thank you; is there any way to override / force this?

Comment: There isn't anyway to override this, it's on a user level and not a setting that's accessible through the API